# how does redirect_to method work in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my update function, the moment something is updated it perfectly goes to `http://localhost:3000/articles/2`

```
 def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

How does the `redirect_to @article` work and show the artiles/2/ page?

Below is my routes

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

Answer (score 4):

The magic method is `polymorphic_url`.

When you call `link_to`, `redirect_to` etc. and you don't pass a string or a hash of routing options Rails will end up calling this method.

Active Record (and Active Model compliant objects) have a `model_name` class method that returns  an ActiveMethod::Name object which has a bunch of methods for obtaining the 'correct' name for a model class for various uses.

One of those (`singular_route_key`) says what name is used for the model in routes. This also takes care of handling things like namespacing if you're in an engine.

In the simplest case, this boils down to

```
@article.class.model_name.singular_route_key #=> 'article'
```

Rails then generates the method name from that by joining this with any prefix options and the correct suffix ('url', 'path', etc.), and ends up with a method name like `article_url`. It then calls that method (generated for you based on your routes file), passing the article, which returns the url for this article.

Answer (score 3):

redirect_to method checks the class of instance provided and gives you the /articles based on the model class, and path provided in routes, and then it check if the object has id or not. If the object persist in database then it checkes for to_params method on that object and add to `/articles/{result of to_params}`. And if the object does not persist in database then it gives you `articles/new`.

Answer (score 2):

See the line with the name `article` -

```
 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
```

So when you give something like `redirect_to @article`, it checks for the id within the current view to get the id and displays that corresponding view of record.

**Scenario:**

**1)** You are in article index with many records being shown.

**2)** You clicked the second record whose link is defined with `redirect_to @article` in a controller.

**3)** The *controller* is smart enough to first route through to identify the route and then  picks the correct path for it.

**4)** The *View* shows the view based on the route forwarded by the controller.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you have

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id]) 

redirect_to @article
```

So `@article` contains the array of `ids` of Article.And also you have `/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show`

So whenever a particular `Article` is updated it redeircts to the corresponding article based on the `:id` which `@article` contains.

In your case,you are updated an article with `id = 2`, so the route is `/artcles/2`